# HtmlEditorExtender does not show Icons

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, htmleditorextender

As the subject says.
I've bound  an HtmlEditorExtender to a textbox but it doesn't show the icons in the toolbar, just grey buttons.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should look something like:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="ContentMail" runat="server" AutoFocus="true" Width="60em" Height="40em" TextMode="MultiLine"/>
 <asp:HtmlEditorExtender ID="HtmlEditorExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="ContentMail" DisplaySourceTab="True">
 </asp:HtmlEditorExtender>
```

And if you are setting it in a TemplateField just add an invisible div with a textbox linked with a HtmlEditorExtender

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same with AjaxControltoolkit 15.1, when I applied Ajax Control Toolkit Static Resources. I had to detach ACTStaticRecourses in order to get my icons back in the toolbar.
Hope this helps to some :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this bug , I add the css style ajaxcontroltoolkit
https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/27732040/

to page when problem and change

background: url(Images/html-editor-buttons.png) no-repeat;

in

```
.ajax__html_editor_extender_button
{
    background: url(Images/html-editor-buttons.png) no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    background-color:#c2c2c2;
    padding-bottom:2px; 
}
```

on pathimage then generic ajax

Answer (score 0):

hey guys(girls) if you using update panel in asp.net or asp:HtmlEditorExtender  using in gridview and don't show icons. You needed add hide asp.panel when contain asp:HtmlEditorExtender  and textbox. Example.

```
  <asp:Panel runat="server" Visible="False">
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox22" runat="server" AutoFocus="true" BackColor="White" Height="15em" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="99%"></asp:TextBox>
                                <ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender ID="TextBox12_HtmlEditorExtender"  runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox22">
                                </ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender></asp:Panel>
```